# error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am trying to rebuild the Apple test App for image detection via CoreML, but I have the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey

```
extension ImageClassificationViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        updateClassifications(for: image)
    }
```

The error comes in the line:

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are using Xcode 10/iOS 12. The signature of the delegate method changed.

Use `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` instead of `String` for the `info` keys.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any])
```

And then use `.originalImage` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.

```
extension ImageClassificationViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)

        let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        updateClassifications(for: image)
    }
```